# How to make individual cell readonly of datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a `datagridview`in my `winform`. I want to make individual `cell` of this datagridview `noneditable` on a specific condition. for this i have tried two methods but any of these not functioning well for me. 
Here is the code

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                if (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "0")
                {
                    row.Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
                    row.Cells[2].Value = "0";
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {

            }
        }
        //if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "0")
        //{
        //    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
        //    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = "0";
        //}
    }
```

the code which is `inside foreach loop` throwing an exception that `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
and the `commented portion of code` set all cells readonly property to true. But what i want that only those cells property set to true where `cell[4].value=0`
Plz suggest me what should i do to make this work better according to condition.

Comment: So it throws an exception - which object reference is null? Does `Cells[4]` have a value that can be converted to a string?

Comment: Have you tried debugging and singlestepping where it throws the error?

Comment: Cells[4] has a value 0 which is coming from database. @Mashton

Comment: Yes!! Exception coming for that cell which Cells[4].value is not zero. @Pavenhimself

Comment: When does it throw the error then, if not in the line row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "0" ?

Comment: Why your doing all these things inside the event "dataGridView1_CellEnter"?

You need to do this after loading the data to grid, if your data is static(Fixed). Other wise you need to do it in Cell changed event.

Comment: when it does not go inside the if body then it throws an exception. @Pavenhimself

Comment: Yes fixed data is actually coming from database. CellChange event also not giving the better solution it also throwing the same exception. @andy

Comment: Ok I'll ask the question in a more direct way. The error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` means that something is null: it has no value but you are performing an operation on it as if it does have a value. So, using your debugger, find out **which object has a null value**. This will tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Definitely row.Cells[4] is null